# Problem parsing JSON result with Prototype

Tags: javascript, json, prototype

My service returns the following JSON object, with the Content-Type header set to "application/javascript". It's wrapped in parens per instructions at json.org][2](http://www.json.org/js.html), but I've tried with and without parens. Without parens, it passes verification from [jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

```
({
  "products": {
    "itemId": "0",
    "productId": "1234",
    "quantity": "4",
    "rank": "12",
    "subProductId": ""
  },
  "txnId": "1"
})
```

If I explicitly eval the response, as shown below, I have no problem:

```
var form = $('productListRequestForm');
form.request({
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    var json = eval(response.responseText);
    rebuildWishlistTable(json);
  },
  onFailure: function(response) {
    alert("AJAX request failed: " + response.responseText);
  }
});
```

However, if I rely on Prototype parsing the response and passing the parsed result as a second parameter to my function as below, that value is always null. According to the [Prototype docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/ajax/request.html), this should work. Is there something that I'm missing, or something that they're missing?

```
var form = $('productListRequestForm');
form.request({
  onSuccess: function(response, json) {
    rebuildWishlistTable(json);
  },
  onFailure: function(response) {
    alert("AJAX request failed: " + response.responseText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Prototype.

At line 1497 in revision 1.6.1, there's the following code:

```
  var contentType = response.getHeader('Content-type');
  if (this.options.evalJS == 'force'
      || (this.options.evalJS && this.isSameOrigin() && contentType
      && contentType.match(/^\s*(text|application)\/(x-)?(java|ecma)script(;.*)?\s*$/i)))
    this.evalResponse();
```

Note that nothing is done with the return from `evalResponse()`. If we then go to the definition of that function:

```
  evalResponse: function() {
    try {
      return eval((this.transport.responseText || '').unfilterJSON());
    } catch (e) {
      this.dispatchException(e);
    }
  },
```

---

Posted a bug on the Prototype site, and it was closed with the comment that I had "several misunderstandings" regarding JSON, and shouldn't be using the bug reporting system to get help. Funny, I thought I was pointing out where they were throwing away a return value.

In case anyone else might have a similar situation, I'm editing my question to show the code that works and that doesn't work, and will be accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Surround it with parenthesis

```
eval("({\"products\"": {\"itemId\": \"0\", \"productId\": \"1234\", \"quantity\": \"4\", \"rank\": \"12\", \"subProductId\": \"\"}, \"txnId\": \"1\"})")
```

That will work for you

Comment: No, actually it doesn't. As I note in my post, the explicit eval works -- and as I also note, I wrap the JSON in parens to do that. The problem is that Prototype's auto-eval doesn't work, whether the JSON is wrapped in parens or not.